# In Swift, Where does Never declare that it conform to Error?

Tags: swift

Code like

```
func alwaysSucceeds(_ completion: (Result<String, Never>) -> Void) {
    completion(.success("yes!"))
}

alwaysSucceeds { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let response):
        print(response)
    }
}
```

works. But I can not find

```
extension Never: Error {}
```

in the Swift Standard Library, anybody knows where I could find it?

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/16857/files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conformance of `Never` to the `Error` protocol was added in the course of implementing

- [SE-0215 Conform `Never` to `Equatable` and `Hashable`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0215-conform-never-to-hashable-and-equatable.md)

in Swift 5. From the [Rationale](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0215-conform-never-to-equatable-and-hashable/13586/45):

> For the same reasons conformances to `Hashable` and `Equatable` are being added to `Never`, the Core Team felt that conformances to `Error` and `Comparable` should also be added to `Never` as part of accepting this proposal. Both of these additional protocol conformances were brought up during the review.

As Leo pointed out, the implementation can be found in [Policy.swift](https://github.com/mdiep/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift):

```
@frozen
public enum Never {}

extension Never: Error {}

extension Never: Equatable, Comparable, Hashable {}
```